# Ploop error creating openvz containers with virtualizor

Tags: openvz, ploop

I'm new to Virtualizor and trying to get started. I installed OpenVZ 7 from ISO ([Version 7.0.8-390 from here](https://download.openvz.org/virtuozzo/releases/)) and everything seemed fine until I installed Virtualizor and tried creating containers. No matter what OS I pick I get

```
Failed to register the CT: PRL_ERR_VZCTL_OPERATION_FAILED (Details: Failed to read /vz/private/3ed73264-6029-4640-b1c0-3e59e635354a.private_temporary/root.hdd/DiskDescriptor.xml: Error in ploop_open_dd (di.c:363): Can't resolve /vz/private/3ed73264-6029-4640-b1c0-3e59e635354a.private_temporary/root.hdd/DiskDescriptor.xml: No such file or directory
Creation of Container private area failed
```

This is due to ploop... so I tried unchecking the ploop setting under Master Settings inside Virualizor and that changed nothing. I then added VE_LAYOUT=simfs to force simfs in /etc/vz/vz.conf and that too changed nothing about the error. It seems to be forcing ploop and I can't figure out why. In addition I'd like to know why ploop is failing. I have ploop and everything installed. Modprobe ploop returns nothing. As does modprobe pfmt_ploop1 modprobe pfmt_raw modprobe pio_direct. The drive is formatted correctly...

df -T

```
Filesystem                      Type    1K-blocks    Used Available Use%    Mounted on
/dev/mapper/openvz_customer-root ext4      65924652 3956032  58596796  7% /
devtmpfs                        devtmpfs  16325968      0  16325968  0% /dev
tmpfs                            tmpfs    16338096      0  16338096  0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                            tmpfs    16338096    9868  16328228  1% /run
tmpfs                            tmpfs    16338096      0  16338096  0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs                            tmpfs      524288      4    524284  1% /tmp
/dev/sda2                        ext4        999320  122304    808204  14% /boot
/dev/mapper/openvz_customer-vz  ext4    878015288  812640 832578776  1% /vz
tmpfs                            tmpfs      3267620      0  3267620  0% /run/user/0
```

uname -a

```
Linux 3.10.0-862.11.6.vz7.64.7 #1 SMP Thu Aug 23 19:33:51 MSK 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Okay I figured it out.

1) You have to change VEFSTYPE to simfs in /etc/vz/vz.conf to use simfs. Virtualizor seems to ignore it's ploop setting on OVZ7... but maybe this was for good reason as I just got errors about the OS template cache being in an invalid format when I tried to force simfs so never mind.

2) The ploop error was caused by /tmp being mounted as a temporary file system that is too small to support the the disk image... and possibly the other hardening mount flags I had set. Removing the mount from fstab fixed the error.

Hope this helps someone down the line.